# using "Payload" as a Map index

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I'm getting crazy whith this, and I'll appreciate any help....

Is there any way to use the value of payload as a map index?.

something like this:

```
<logger message = "the value is #[flowVars.MyMap['#[payload]'] doc:name="Logger""/>
```

Thanks in advance

alf.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `#[flowVars.MyMap[payload]]`